# A function to merge two vectors into a dataframe keeping its vector names

Tags: r

I have two vectors

```
randomName1 = c(4,5,6,3,2,1)
randomName2 = c(3,4,5,6,7,4)
```

can easily merge into a dataframe with this simple function

```
fun = function(x, y) {
    df = data.frame(x, y)
   df
}

fun(randomName1,randomName2)
  x y
1 4 3
2 5 4
3 6 5
4 3 6
5 2 7
6 1 4
```

but the vectors have lost their names. You can add two more arguments to the function and do this:

```
fun = function(x, y, name1, name2) {
   df = data.frame(x, y)
   colnames(df) = c(name1, name2)
   df
}

fun(randomName1, randomName2, "randomName1", "randomName2")
  randomName1 randomName2
1           4           3
2           5           4
3           6           5
4           3           6
5           2           7
6           1           4
```

But in this case, we need extra arguments and can't just pass in the vectors directly. Is there a simple way to keep the name of the vectors as column names of the dataframe without adding more function arguments?

Comment: Try `tibble(randomName1, randomName2)`

Comment: Or frankly, why not just `fun <- function(...) data.frame(...)`? But then, that sort of begs the question of why not just use `data.frame()` directly.

Comment: Hi, Joran. This is the simplified version of the real code, evidently the original function does much more than simply joining two vectors and would like to use as few arguments as possible. :)

Comment: So make the first argument `...` and the you can add other subsequent arguments, and simply pass `...` along to `data.frame()` inside the function, and then continue with your other actions.

Comment: Sorry @joran, I didn't quite understand what you were trying to say in your comments until divibisan wrote the answer. Thank you also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you pass the 2 vectors into your function using the arguments `x` and `y` they get renamed within the scope of the function as `x` and `y`. Thus, when you put them into a data frame with `data.frame(x,y)`, their new names are preserved in `colnames`.

To prevent this, you need to pass them in with their original names, which you can do using `...`:

```
f <- function(...) {
    df <- data.frame(...)
    return(df)
}

f(randomName1, randomName2)
  randomName1 randomName2
1           4           3
2           5           4
3           6           5
4           3           6
5           2           7
6           1           4
```

The `...` argument grabs all arguments that are not assigned to a named argument and makes them available in the function. Since we didn't assign `randomName1` and `randomName2` to an argument, they get passed into `data.frame` with their original names, and those names are saved in `df`